# How to get the anonymizing_video_by_DSFD running

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, resnet

My goal is to use [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/JeiKeiLim/Anonymizing_video_by_DSFD) to blur the faces of my input videos.

Current progress and problems: I have cloned the repo and then get familiar with it. But when I try to get it running on my end, I keep getting error messages like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 261, in <module> 
    test_oneimage()
  File "demo.py", line 230, in test_oneimage
    det0 = infer(net, img, transform, thresh, cuda, shrink)
  File "demo.py", line 107, in infer
    y = net(x)  # forward pass
  File "/home/lakeside/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lakeside/Desktop/Anonymizing_video_by_DSFD/face_ssd.py", line 342, in forward
    output = self.detect(
  File "/home/lakeside/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 159, in __call__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated. Please use new-style autograd function with static forward method. (Example: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function)
```

And then I try to search a solution for resolving this, I have tried to add **@staticmethod** before the forward method and use something like:

```
y = net.apply(x)
```

But then it gives me error that:

```
demo.py:103: UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead.
  x = Variable(x.unsqueeze(0), volatile=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 261, in <module>
    test_oneimage()
  File "demo.py", line 230, in test_oneimage
    det0 = infer(net, img, transform, thresh, cuda, shrink)
  File "demo.py", line 107, in infer
    y = net.apply(x)  # forward pass
  File "/home/lakeside/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 473, in apply
    module.apply(fn)
  File "/home/lakeside/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 473, in apply
    module.apply(fn)
  File "/home/lakeside/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 474, in apply
    fn(self)
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I have tried to figure this out, but no luck so far. I see [on this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/eel6yd/p_i_have_built_a_face_detector_to_blur_faces_for/) that there are some people get it work successfully.